# Can someone help me understand this?

Tags: python, python-3.x

So I have a quick question about the below code. In the program it will display a series of dashes to match the random word selected. When the player guesses, the program goes through a loop that checks the guess. My question is, and what I'm really confused over, is how does the program know to replace the exact dash needed to display an accurate and partially revealed word? and what is new += so_far[i] doing? overall, that section really confuses me and I would greatly appreciate some clarification. Thanks!

```
MAX_WRONG = len(HANGMAN) - 1

# creating list of random words
WORDS = ("TECHNOLOGY", "PYTHON", "SCRIPT", "PROCESSOR", "RANDOM",     "COMPUTING")

# initialize variables
word = random.choice(WORDS)

so_far = "-" * len(word) # one dash for every letter in the word to be guessed

wrong = 0 # number of wrong guesses made

used = []  # letters already guessed

# creating the main loop
print("Welcome to Hangman. Good luck!")

while wrong < MAX_WRONG and so_far != word:
    print(HANGMAN[wrong])
    print("\nYou've used the following letters:\n", used)
    print("\nSo far, the word is:\n", so_far)

# getting the player's guess
    guess = input("\n\nEnter your guess: ")
    guess = guess.upper()

    while guess in used:

        print("You've already guessed the letter", guess)
        guess = input("\nEnter your guess: ")
        guess = guess.upper()

    used.append(guess)

# checking the guess
    if guess in word:
        print("\nYes!", guess, "is in the word!")

    # create a new so_far to include guess
        new = ""

        for i in range(len(word)):
            if guess == word[i]:
                new += guess
            else:
                new += so_far[i]
        so_far = new

    else:
        print("\nSorry,", guess, "isn't in the word.")
        wrong += 1

# ending the game

if wrong == MAX_WRONG:
    print(HANGMAN[wrong])
    print("\nYou lose!")
else:
    print("\nYou guessed it!")

print("The word was:", word)

ext()
```

Comment: Code review possibly?

Comment: What does that mean? The program runs fine. I just want clarification on what the for i in range(len(word)) block is exactly doing and how it replacing the dashes of the unrevealed/partially revealed word in the correct places.

Comment: i understand it now guys thanks

Answer (score 0):

You are looking out for this section in the code which does that

```
for i in range(len(word)):
    if guess == word[i]:
        new += guess
    else:
        new += so_far[i]
so_far = new
```

Say if you guess the word 'S' and say if the word to be guessed is 'Super'

Initial state

```
Sofar : -----
```

During the iteration process a variable `'new'` is assigned the value for each word match. if not matched take that value from so_far[i]
In our case

Length of word  = len('Super') = 5
Iter 1: will only go to ig loop since 'S' occurs only once.

This means all other iterations go to else condition and since all `so_far[i] has '-'` as values.
So after the first loop of iteration your values look like this

```
new: S----
```

At the end of loop reassign `new` to `so_far`. This means now `'so_far'` variable has changed from `'-----'` to `'S----'`.

I suggest you to use a pdb to debug above the for loop and get the details when you get to such doubts in future.

Hope this helps.